# In applescript how to press 5 keys when 1 key is pressed?

Tags: macos, applescript

supporters

I'm not experienced with applescript and am learning. Please don't laugh if this is too easy.

My intention is to press 5 Qs when user presses F. The F keystroke should be listened globally.

For now I've only managed to press those Qs...

tell application "System Events"
    repeat while 1 is 1
        #there should be some kind if if condition which I have no grasp on...
        keystroke "QQQQQ"
        delay (random number from 1 to 2)
    end repeat
end tell

Comment: I also wish to make the mouse click the current location. I googled but most other people are trying to click a specific location. How can I just click wherever the current location is? thanks!

Comment: AppleScript is not able to detect keystrokes.

Comment: o .... okay.... got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well. after some googling and reading the comment. I realised it's impossible.